# can't convert string to int angular4

Tags: angular

I'm using bootstrap 4 with Angular 2 and have the following select:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="isActived" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Add BY</label>
    <div class="col-sm-16">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let user of users">
            <select class="custom-select" *ngIf="user.name == test" name="State" required
                [(ngModel)]="model.isActived" #isActived="ngModel">
                <option selected value="0">{{test}}</option>
            </select>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

My first question is when i use this selected i can't get it as default

my second one is how i can convert the value of test to integer i get this error:
"message": "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value:
i use the parseInt() and many solution but i still have the same error

```js
getAllUsers() {
    this.userService
        .showAllUsers()
        .subscribe(users => {
            this.users = users;
            let userData = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');

            if (!userData) return null;

            let userrData = JSON.parse(userData);
            var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
            const tokenPayload = decode(userrData.token, {complete: true});

            for (let user of users) {
                if (tokenPayload.sub == user.id) {
                    parseInt(this.test = user.name);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

so can i get some help

Comment: If `user.name` is a `string` but you want it to be a `number`, you can use the syntax `this.test = +user.name` to convert it to a `number`. If you want to use `parseInt(..)`, you need to swap your code to `this.test = parseInt(user.name, 10)`

Comment: thank you, but  Now the test  give me NAN

Comment: That would be because `user.name` is not a number. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: yes it's string

Comment: The contents of the string are not a number. If it was a number it would return a number after parsing. Are you sure `user.name` is the property that you want to convert to a number?

Comment: I put the value of test in a field isActived of type number in my data base thats why i get this error so i try to  convert user.name to a number but it seem a wrong way

Comment: Did you try by using  function  " Number(string) "  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this function (Number) to convert a string to a number.

Example:

```
let value = Number(item.someString);
```